# Tetration by a Non-Integer

Tags: soft-question, tetration, hyperoperation

Does anyone think that tetration by a non-integer will *ever* be defined ... *really properly*?

Great mathematicians struggled with finding an implementation of the non-integer *factorial* for a long time to no avail ... and then eventually Leonhard Euler devised a means of doing it, & by a sleight-of-mind that was just so *slick* & so *simple* in its essence ... and yet so *radical*! Is there any scope for another such *sleight-of-mind* as that, whereby someone might do similarly for tetration, or have they all been *used-up*? It's impossible to conceive of how there might be any truly new conceptual resource left of that kind. But it's actually tautological that that is so, because the kind  I am talking about is precisely the kind that is *essentially radically new*, & of even how it *might be thought* hitherto unconceived!

But the attempts I have seen so far at defining tetration by general real number look to me for all the world like mere *interpolation* - some of them indeed very thorough & cunning & ingenious (insofar as I can follow them *atall*) - but lacking that spark of *essential innovation* that is evinced in Euler's definition of the gamma function.

Just incase it seems I have gotten lost in philosophy, I'll repeat the question: will there ever be a definition of tetration by general real number that resolves the matter *as thoroughly* as Euler's definition of the gamma-function resolved the matter of *factorial* of general real number?

Comment: I am no expert on history, but googling yields the name "Leonhard Euler." I am unsure where you get the "t"...

Comment: I once read the appendix to TE Lawrence's _Seven Pillars of Wisdom_ ... I think it was a bad influence on me!

Answer (score 3):

[We're trying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Complex_heights), but it's hard.

A better analogy than the Gamma function would be the way you can now define $x^y$ for real $y$. Why does $x^{3/2}$ make sense? Because I can solve $y^2=x^3$. (Admittedly any solution $y=y_0$ implies $y<y_0$ is a solution too, but we have a convention to get around that for $x>0$.)

So what would ${}^{3/2}x$ mean? Presumably, a solution of $y^y=x^{x^x}$ (although, as @GottfriedHelms notes, we can't expect a solution of ${}^2y={}^3x$ to also satisfy ${}^{2k}y={}^{3k}x$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$). Unfortunately, the values of $y^y$ for $y\in (0,\,\frac{1}{e})$ are repeated again for some $y>\frac{1}{e}$ in a... not particularly simple way, so it's already getting confusing. There are similar headaches when trying to define ${}^{k/(2l)}x$ for $x>0,\,k,\,l\in\mathbb{N},\,2\nmid k$.

(On second thoughts, ${}^42=2^{2^{2^2}}=2^{2^4}=2^{16}$ but ${}^2({}^22)=(2^2)^{2^2}=4^4=2^8$, so there's no ${}^{ab}x={}^a({}^bx)$ rule we can use in the above manner anyway.)

I'm not sure whether you can even prove ${}^yx$ with $y$ irrational can be defined by continuity, i.e. whether we can prove any rational sequence $y_n$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=y$ gives the same $n\to\infty$ limit of ${}^{y_n}x$.

Having said all that, I bet we'll have made a lot of progress within 200 years (even if only in [proving what we can't do](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/problem)).

Comment: I can't answer this as thoroughly as I would like to at the present moment - but one little item stands out - _to me_, at least, the most fundamental definition of $x^a$ for general real $a$ is that it is the solution of the differential equation $dy/dx =ay/x$ & $1^a = 1$ forall $a$. But I am _very_ fond of that _scheme_ of mathematics inwhich functions are _essentially defined_ by differential equations - as being solutions of them - that as the _axiom_ of what they are.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of E.Schroeder in the 19'th century for bases $b$ (allowing two real fixpoints for iterations, for instance $b=\sqrt{2}$) , sometimes called "regular iteration" seems to me a real good one. It allows a meaningful expression for fractional iteration *from some starting point $z_0$ towards some endpoint $z_h$* where $h$ means the (possibly fractional, even complex) iteration-(*h*)eight, such that $z_0$ is the initial value, $z_1 = b^{z_0}$ is the first (integer) iteration and so on.

However, that method needs conjugacy to be able to be applied to all real $z_0$ : one has to choose the appropriate fixpoint for shifting the power-series for the exponentiation with base $b$ and get an evaluatable analytical answer at all.
Unfortunately it has been observed, that in the cases $z_0$ where each fixpoint-conjugacy can be taken, the results of fractional iteration are different - even if only by some *1e-25* or so.

A basic problem for the general $b$ is the multivaluedness of the complex exponentiation/logarithmization, or say, the "clock-arithmetic" with respect to the $2 \pi î$-term in the exponentiation - I have once seen an article (R.Corless & al.) on the "winding number" which tries to make sense of introduction of one more parameter for the complex numbers to overcome that "clock-arithmetic" to a real-arithmetic. But that was no real progress for the problem here.

So I think, similarly to the full workout of L. Euler about the multivaluedness of the logarithm and then the representation of the gamma-function as an infinite sum of partial products, we need some more idea here - the E. Schroeder-idea seems to me just like a small insular solution, however nice ever...

*(just as a remark: you might consider the **two** common versions of the interpolation of the **Fibonacci numbers** $fib(n)$ to continuous functions of the index: there is one ansatz providing real numbers for real index, and another ansatz (in analogy perhaps to the Schroeder method) which gives complex numbers for real indexes but seems more smooth when seen overall in the complex plane. See a small essay about this [at my homepage](http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/FracIterAltGeom.htm))*

Comment: I presume that by "the first ansatz" you mean the φⁿ±φ⁻ⁿ thing. I have _nod idea_ about the other, but I am very curious about it now, especially as you say it is an instance of the _Schroeder method_ ... which sounds like it could do with 'tapering' by means of a nice familiar & relatively simple example for someone coaching themself in it from the beginning! Anyway - thank-you for the information ... but it dashed my hopes a bit when you began to speak of it being _yet another_ insular effort. But I think (i) it does require fundamentally new thought (ii) it _is_ there - _yet to be found_!

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey: thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I'm much busy this and next days and have no space to step in again. Let's see end of next week...

Comment: Of course I don't _expect_ you to dispense me a _course_ on the Schroeder method! On the contrary, thankyou for taking the trouble to steer my attention in that direction. And I do often just _throw ideas out __without___ the expectation that those who catch them _process_ or _develop_ them for me!

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey: I've found my old discussion about the interpolation of the fibonacci numbers, I've added the link to my remark in my answer. First I thought I'd posted that as Q&A here in MSE but I did not know this place here and communicated via the sci.math-newsgroup in the usenet. Hope the essay is helpful/explanative about my remark.

Comment: Looks ike you're giving me a course of instruction anyway! That's your work? I think I can discern your style of writing in it. I've only just looked at it - it'll take a while for that to mature. I see the 'other' form of the 'continuous-isation' of the fibonacci numbers - a _spiral_ in the complex plane. Thanks for your ongoing attention ... please don't be tempted to make inroads into your time ... it wasn't meant as a subtle goad or anything when I said I don't _expect_ a course of instruction, and plenty to be fornow.¶ Thanks for that direction - I shall assuredly enjoy delving into that.

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey . :-) Thanks for your kind words! Well, I just couldn't sleep well in the night and was idle looking in my old directories, curious when and where I'd discussed this. Now here is sunday morning and I've another small time before breakfast when my love comes back from her nordic-walking tour... Have an interesting day with that problem!

Comment: Just got your last 'comment'! I was about to write this - that there is a truly remarkable formula for the taylor series of iterates of x→x^f(x) when x=e^z, such that i_0≡1, i_1≡e^z, i_2≡e^(ze^z). It's too complicated to cram into one of these little comment boxes, partly because the coefficients are those of the lambert_w function upto k=n, and then 'switch' to being generated by a recursion on the coefficients from 0 through k-1 on the same row _and_ on the previous row. Whether it's susceptible of the treatment you've shown, don't know; but you've got that 'discontinuity'in the generation.

Comment: Ah, just found this, likely it can inspire on the route of finding the "thorough" solution (it such exists at all...) It is a visual comparision of three methods of interpolation of tetration.see http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/ComparisionOfInterpolations.pdf I've myself tried to get a deeper understanding of the mysteries of the "best" power series - but this is still some conceptual reasoning in mind, not much explicite work-out, and short discussion in our tetration-forum in the 2010's.

Comment: One more much interesting discussion about such mysteries of powerseries has been done by Leonard Euler, under the title "a false logarithm" (or so) nicely presented by an editor at ams, having made a series of exhibitory articels on interesting pieces of Euler. I have it, but just have to leave now. Google for *ams* *hedi* (how-euler-did-it) and "false logarithm". Euler discusses a series which is fine for logarithm at integer powers but fails at fractional powers. Much instructive for hidden insufficience of some powerseries-ansatz. And resembles to common powerseries for tetration...

Comment: (upps: correction in previous comment:)  ...  "thorough" solution (***if*** such exists at all...) It is a visual ...

Comment: Three comments arrived whilst I was writing! ¶ I have ventured to frame the exposition of the powerseries I was just telling you about as a full-on _answer_, knowing that doing-so would _bump_ this post; but I think that's not unreasonable as it _is_ a bona-fide self-answer that _does_ progress the question; and I have not been in the habit of bumping this post. But it conveys clearly now the function I was talking about. ¶ Yes that 'false logarithm' ... I've heard of that.

Comment: _And_ of course the example of the 'false' logarithm is do doubt something you adduce as a _parable_ against supposing that this Taylor series, remarkable though it is, is really of much avail in developing what _non_ integer tetration might be. It probably _isn't_ ultimately. But all the same I _do_ think it is a real _gem_. ¶ But I seem to have made a very good job of distracting you already! I haven't forgotten what you said a few comments back ... and you have already furnished me with an ample amount for keeping me going for quite a while yet!

Comment: @Gottried Helms -- Just been having a closer look at that _Eulers false logarithm_ -- it's not quite what it seems at first is it!? In some ways though, that audacious cunning of it only goes to show Euler's genius the more, in a sense ... I mean what if he _had_ just turned out _yet one more_ slick series for something ... whereas this is an item of a somewhat _slanted_ nature!

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey: I'm just getting my attention here again. I've compiled a small set of three textfiles from old math-discussion related to this here. One more (and more explanative) to the "false series for log", one on "superroots" which deals with a power-series which seems to be related to your invention (just on a glance) and a third on historically first use of the technical term "logarithm". See http://go.helms-net/math/tetdocs/_other/OldNotes.zip I hope you'll find it still interesting ...

Answer (score 0):

There is a remarkable expression I've found in this connection that might have some bearing on the matter for the iterates the Taylor series of $$\operatorname{f}(x)\to x^{\operatorname{f}(x)}$$ when $x\equiv e^z$, such that $$\operatorname{f_0}(x)\equiv1 ,$$$$\operatorname{f_1}(x)\equiv \exp(z) ,$$$$\operatorname{f_2}(x)\equiv \exp(z\exp(z)) ,$$ etc. The coefficients for $k=0\dots n$ are those of the Lambert W-function; but thereafter, for $k>n$ the coefficients are given by the following recursion. Let $a_{n,0}=1\forall n$, $a_{0,k}=0$ for $k>0$, & thereafter $$a_{n,k}={1\over n}\sum_{j=1}^k ja_{n,k-j}a_{n-1,j-1} .$$ These coefficients are in a sense 'wasted' upthrough $k=n$, inthat they do not actually *appear* in the Taylor series; and yet they still serve the function of being necessary for the generation of the coefficients that *do* appear. It is fascinating to my mind, the way there is a kind of *discontinuity* in the series - the coeffiecients generated by this recursion 'peeling-away' one-at-a -time as $n$ is incremented, 'revealing' the coefficients of the Lambert W-function 'underneath'; and it is a well known result that the limit as the $$\operatorname{f}(x)\to x^{\operatorname{f}(x)}$$ tends to $\infty$ *is indeed* the Lambert W-function.

Whether this is susceptible of treatment by *Schroeder's* method I would not venture definitely to say at the present time, as, though I see in outline how that method can be applied to something like the recursion that gives the *Fibonacci* numbers, I am rather *daunted* by that *discontinuity* in the generation of the coefficients in *this* case; and I cannot see at a glance how it would be encoded.

Comment: Ambrette- you might look at my older discussion cited in my new answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3056786/1714